# Do extra NAA flags after 1 NAA flag get ignored?

Tags: support, flags, not-an-answer

From what I understand, it takes 1 NAA flag to have that post go into the Low Quality Queue and/or Mod Queue.

From there, it needs to get 6 recommended deletes for it to be deleted or 1 delete vote by a mod from the mod queue.

That is not what this question is about though.

I'm wondering if say, I link the NAA post to a chat room, informing others about the NAA and say 7 other users flag it as NAA. Do those extra 7 NAA flags do anything? Are they just ignored?

I know that by flagging the post as NAA it will lock those flaggers out of the LQRQ for reviewing that post. Does it still need 6 recommend deletions for it to be deleted, or would those 7 other NAA flags have already deleted that NAA post?

Comment: @iCodez [Actually, they do get thrown into the LQP queue.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/237685)

Comment: @hichris123 - Huh, I never knew that.  Thanks for the link.  I'll delete my old comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not ignored, but they don't delete the post directly either. Rather, they require the post to get more Looks OK reviews to get out of the Low Quality review queue.

> Effective # of reviews required == ReviewsRequired + # of applicable flags (where ReviewsRequired is 2 on Stack Overflow, 1 everywhere else). So 1 VLQ or NAA flag means EffectiveReviewsRequired=3.

So,  7 NAA flags make the post much less likely to exit the review via Looks OK: it would need 9 reviewers to choose "Looks OK". Chances are, either someone will edit, or there will be enough "delete" reviews by then.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/259867)